# TPIL 4.4: example : ¬ (∃ x, ¬ p x) → (∀ x, p x)

Tags: lean

Section 4.4 of Theorem Proving in Lean shows the following:

```
example : (∀ x, p x) ↔ ¬ (∃ x, ¬ p x) := sorry
```

Here I'll focus on the right-to-left case:

```
¬ (∃ x, ¬ p x) → (∀ x, p x)
```

## Approach 1

We know that we'll have a parameter of type `¬ (∃ x, ¬ p x)` so let's start with that:

```
example : ¬ (∃ x, ¬ p x) → (∀ x, p x) := 

    (assume hnExnpx : ¬ (∃ x, ¬ p x),

        _)
```

We know that we'll have to return an expression of type `(∀ x, p x)` so let's begin constructing that:

```
example : ¬ (∃ x, ¬ p x) → (∀ x, p x) := 

    (assume hnExnpx : ¬ (∃ x, ¬ p x),

        (λ x, _))
```

At this point we need to return a value of type `p x` and it isn't clear that we can build one at this point. Perhaps we need to try to come up with a `false` value.

The function `hnExnpx` returns `false` given a `(∃ x, ¬ p x)`. So let's try to build one of those, apply `hnExnpx` to it and then use `false.elim`:

```
example : ¬ (∃ x, ¬ p x) → (∀ x, p x) := 

    (assume hnExnpx : ¬ (∃ x, ¬ p x),

        (λ x,

            false.elim (hnExnpx (exists.intro x (λ hpx, _)))

        ))
```

And now we're back to needing another `false` value.

## Approach 2

Chapter 3 mentioned that sometimes classical logic is needed.

A naive approach which uses `(em (∀ x, p x))` leads us here:

```
example : ¬ (∃ x, ¬ p x) → (∀ x, p x) := 

    (assume hnExnpx : ¬ (∃ x, ¬ p x),

        or.elim (em (∀ x, p x))

            (λ hAxpx, hAxpx)

            (λ hnAxpx : ¬ (∀ x, p x), (λ x, _))

    )
```

Again, we'll need a `p x` value or a `false`. The only new thing we have is `hnAxpx : ¬∀ (x : α), p x`. It's still not clear how to get a `p x`. `hnAxpx` does return false but we'd need a `(∀ x, p x)` which is the original thing we're looking for. :-)

Perhaps this one involves a more elaborate use of classical logic?

Any suggestions are welcome!

---

**UPDATE**

Here's an approach based on the comment by simon1505475 below which appears to work:

example : ¬ (∃ x, ¬ p x) → (∀ x, p x) :=

```
(assume hnExnpx : ¬ (∃ x, ¬ p x),

    (λ x, 

        or.elim (em (p x))

            (λ hpx : p x, hpx)

            (λ hnpx : ¬ p x, 

                false.elim (hnExnpx (exists.intro x (λ hpx : p x, hnpx hpx))))))
```

Comment: Have you tried `em` on `p x` for a specific `x`?

Comment: @simon1505475 That's the hint that I needed... Thank you!

Comment: In a similar context, Johan on Zulip is suggesting the a proof by contradiction would also work.

Comment: @simon1505475 I've updated the question to show an approach based on your hint. Thanks again!